# How to inquire cascade operations order with Hibernate/JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Lately I've been using JPA/Hibernate with good success, but I still have troubles finding errors in my entities, especially when the error arise from a cascading persist operation.

We use a quite complex database design, and with many relations, and my usual persisting approach consists in setting up a set of entities, assign all the links between them and then calling `persist()` on the root entity.

Sometimes this results in an `SELECT` error, in which Hibernate complains that it could not find an entity given the identifier.
This even though Hibernate was supposed to `INSERT` that entity in the first place.

Most often than not this is a problem of cascading, and it could be easily debugged if I had a way for asking Hibernate what operations it intends to perform (and in which order) to achieve the `persist()` I'm asking.

How can I obtain a feedback for Hibernate persisting strategy?

I know how to ask for SQL logs, but those are usually very obscure and verbose, and not at all explicit about why some SQL commands are stated.

---

As a practical example, this morning I got stuck a bit on this kind of exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find foo.bar.product.model.entity.FooEntity with id 113381; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find foo.bar.product.model.entity.FooEntity with id 113381
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:389)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.save(Unknown Source)
    at foo.bar.product.model.service.WorkloadService.updateAndSaveAllDependeceWithNewWklId(WorkloadService.java:154)
    at foo.bar.product.model.service.WorkloadService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9cf9789e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at foo.bar.product.model.service.WorkloadService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1e47513d.updateAndSaveAllDependeceWithNewWklId(<generated>)
    at foo.bar.product.FooFunction.run(FooFunction.java:137)
    at foo.bar.product.FunctionSelectorMain.run(FunctionSelectorMain.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:789)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:779)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:769)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
    at foo.bar.product.FunctionSelectorMain.main(FunctionSelectorMain.java:29)
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find foo.bar.product.model.entity.FooEntity with id 113381
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:632)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:518)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:663)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.replace(AbstractType.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replaceAssociations(TypeHelper.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:427)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:840)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:822)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:827)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1161)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor45.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:509)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:540)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 27 more
```

and the problem here simply was a missing persist cascade in one of the entities related to FooEntity, but finding which one of them was painful without proper Hibernate output.

Comment: Could you please post the exception you are getting?

Comment: I would recommend to analyze wether you object graph contains cycles. This could be the reason for your problem.

Comment: I added an example, but my question is not about this particular debug, because given time I usually get to the end of bugs. The question is about how to get proper logs from Hibernate to investigate this kind of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I have found Hibernate's class responsible for cascading JPA operations.

In general it's enough to increase log level for `org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade` to `TRACE` and useful messages appears.

The message will explain for each entity what other entities will be subject to operations due to cascade definitions.

For example in my Spring Boot `application.properties` file I have written:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

in order to properly debug cascading operations and their SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you are stuck with the SQL logs.

Due to transactions, persistence to the database is the only time you can determine what's being put in the database.

You can of course have a reasonable idea of the order of persistence by looking at the domain model and the transactions, but for complex operations it becomes a headache.